Rspamd tries to load dkim signing key althought the dkim_signing module is disabled
I'm using Rspamd as part of my MTA setup.
For signing the outgoing mails, I decided to use OpenDKIM instead of Rspamd so I disabled the Rspamd's dkim_signing module. To accomplish this, I simply renamed
/etc/rspamd/modules.d/dkim_signing.conf to /etc/rspamd/modules.d/dkim_signing.conf.STOP

Now everything works as expected, the messages are signed by OpenDKIM, but where a message enters the system, I can see the following within the Rspamd logs:
 <96186d>; task; dkim_module_load_key_format: cannot load dkim key /var/lib/rspamd/dkim/example.com.dkim.key: cannot stat key file: '/var/lib/rspamd/dkim/example.com.dkim.key' No such file or directory

What is the problem here?
Tried nothing more, I expected the DKIM signing functionality of Rspamd to be disabled.
